# What's the nowcasting "bible"?

Tags: forecasting, references

Is there an accepted best text about nowcasting that you would recommend for someone getting into the field?

Comment: Not sure if there is a text, but papers by Giannone, Reichlin, and Banbura, would be recommended. Check the European Central Bank working paper series.

Comment: I think even the hope for a 'bible' on such things is counterproductive. Any text on topics such as fall under CV's remit should be approached from a skeptical viewpoint (believe what you have been given sufficient reason to accept). No book is without its flaws, and a few errors are to be expected in even very good books.

Comment: I also think the hope for a *single* text as the fount of all knowledge is a mistake. Different books approach topics from different points of view, and each may cover important topics others do not. Some very flawed books may also have some great value, if approached from an appropriately critical standpoint. When learning a topic, I generally try to look at at least half a dozen books of various vintages and levels. Sometimes I'll then settle on a few that seem especially good, but I rarely feel comfortable with only a single text on a topic.

Comment: Thanks Graeme.  Glen, if no bible do you ahve a reference or two worth reading?